# How do I replace a string value with an image?

Tags: php

I have a web page presenting data from my MySQL database. Where there is the word 'flag', I want the image of the flag to replace it. I know what I have done is (clearly) not right, but I am struggling to find a solution (in layman terms).

[This what it does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDbgO.png)

```
<?php

require_once "db_config.php";

$sql = "SELECT username, message, time, type FROM notice_board ORDER BY time DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["time"]. " | ". $row["type"]. " | ". $row["message"] . "<br>";

        if ($row["type"]="flag")
        {
          echo '<img width=10 height=10 src="./media/notice_board/flag.png" />';
        }

        else if ($row["type"]="information")
        {
          echo '<img width=10 height=10 src="./media/notice_board/info.png" />';
        }

        else if ($row["type"]="stop")
        {
          echo '<img width=10 height=10 src="./media/notice_board/stop.png" />';
        }

        else if ($row["type"]="warning")
        {
          echo '<img width=10 height=10 src="./media/notice_board/important.png" />';
        }

        else if ($row["type"]="question")
        {
          echo '<img width=10 height=10 src="./media/notice_board/question.png" />';
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "There are no new notices as of yet today";
}

?>
```

Comment: `$row["type"]="flag"` should be `$row["type"]=="flag"` - note the two `==`. A single `=` sets the value whereas dounble tests for equality. The same holds true for the other conditional tests you have which I guess are also failing

Comment: If you change the name of the image file `info.png` to `information.png` and `important.png` to warning.png` there is no need for any `if() / else if()` . In that case just use `$row['type']` as filename.

Answer (score 0):

`=` is the assignment operator, not the equality check operator. Instead you should use the `===` operator. E.g.:

```php
if ($row["type"] === "flag") {
  # Here --------^
  echo '<img width=10 height=10 src="./media/notice_board/flag.png" />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the misuse of the single `=` rather than `==` or even `===` you might streamline the code a little to reduce duplication

```
<?php

    require_once "db_config.php";

    $sql = "SELECT username, message, time, type FROM notice_board ORDER BY time DESC";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        
            switch( $row["type"] ){
                case 'flag':$src='flag.png';break;
                case 'information':$src='info.png';break;
                case 'stop':$src='stop.png';break;
                case 'warning':$src='important.png';break;
                case 'question':$src='question.png';break;
                default:$src='info.png';break;// a suitable default perhaps
            }
            printf(
                '%s | %s | %s <br /><img width=10 height=10 src="./media/notice_board/%s" />',
                $row["time"],
                $row["type"],
                $row["message"],
                $src
            );
        }
    } else {
        echo "There are no new notices as of yet today";
    }

?>
```